# Fetching Texting and numbers from Image Clicked in Android

Tags: android, image, camera

I am trying to click a image from camera and then trying to get the text and numbers within the image and display in textview in android. I am confused about how to achieve this through my Java code. Does anyone had a similar problem and knows how to solve it? I would be grateful if somebody could help me!Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to get text from an image. You can see [this](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr)